# How to derive an objective function for a multi-class logistic regression classifier using 1-of-k encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

I get what this wiki page says(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression), but I don't know how to get the update rules for stochastic gradient descent. Sorry to ask this here(this is really just about machine learning theories instead of actual implementation). Could someone provide a solution with explanation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to write code to implent softmax, I refer most to the page http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Softmax_Regression

this is the code I wrote in matlab ,hope it will help

```
function y = sigmoid_multi(weight,x,class_index)
%%  weight feature_dim * class_num
%%  x      feature_dim * 1
%%  class_index  scalar
    sum = eps;
    class_num = size(weight,2);
    for i = 1:class_num
        sum = sum + exp(weight(:,i)'*x);
    end
    y = exp(weight(:,class_index)'*x)/sum;
end

function g = gradient(train_patterns,train_labels,weight)
    m = size(train_patterns,2);
    class_num = size(weight,2);
    g = zeros(size(weight));
    for j = 1:class_num
        for i = 1:m
            if(train_labels(i) == j)
                g(:,j) = g(:,j) + (1 - log( sigmoid_multi(weight,train_patterns(:,i),j) + eps))*train_patterns(:,i);
            end
        end
    end
    g = -(g/m);
end
function J = object_function(train_patterns,train_labels,weight)
    m = size(train_patterns,2);
    J = 0;
    for i = 1:m
        J = J + log( sigmoid_multi(weight,train_patterns(:,i),train_labels(i)) + eps);
    end
    J = -(J/m);
end

function weight = multi_logistic_train(train_patterns,train_labels,alpha)
%%  weight feature_dim * class_num
%%  train_patterns  featur_dim * sample_num
%%  train_labels  1 * sample_num
%%  alpha   scalar
     class_num = length(unique(train_labels));
     m = size(train_patterns,2); %% sample_number;
     n = size(train_patterns,1); % feature_dim;
     weight = rand(n,class_num);
     for i = 1:40
        J = object_function(train_patterns,train_labels,weight);
        fprintf('objec function value : %f\n',J);
        weight = weight - alpha*gradient(train_patterns,train_labels,weight);
     end    
end
```